# Received data through a POST Request always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have server and a client the server uses `node js` the client send requests to the sever and the server should act accordingly.
However I came across a little bit of a confusing behavior and i want to know why its behaving like that!
The thing is when i send a `json array` or `Object` the received data by the server is always empty for some reason.

Here is the code of the request that raises the problem:

```js
function Save()
{ // saves the whole global data by sending it the server in a save request
  if( global_data.length > 0)
  {
    var url = "http://localhost:3000/save";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    };
    let object={ id: "101.jpg", RelativePath: "images/101.jpg", size: 61103 }; // this just an exemple of data 
    let data_json = JSON.stringify(object);
    request.send(data_json);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Nothing to save");
  }
}
```

And Here is the server code related to this request:

```js
const server=http.createServer(onRequest)
server.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('server listening at http://localhost:3000');
})

function onRequest (request, response) {
    /*function that handles the requests received by the server and
    sends back the appropriate response*/

    /*allowing Access-Control-Allow-Origin since the server is run on local host */
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');


    console.log("a request received :" ,request.url);

    let parsed_url = url.parse(request.url);
    if(parsed_url.pathname == '/save')
    {
        console.log("Proceeding to save state : ...");

        let received_data = '';
        request.on('data', function(chunck) {
            received_data += chunck;
            console.log("another line of data received");
        });
        request.on('end', function() {
            console.log(received_data); // why is this empty (my main problem)?
            let jsondata = JSON.parse(received_data); // here raises the error since the received data is empty
            console.log(jsondata);
            response.writeHeader(200,{"content-Type":'text/plain'});
            response.write("SAVED!");
            response.end()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: just if anyone got the same problem: for me I couldn't solve it directly so I was forced to use `query-string` in order to parse the data instead of `json.parse` it seems the data received emptiness was related to the failure of the JSON parser somehow.
so I installed it with `npm install querystring`  and used `const qs = require('querystring');` in order to invoque the parser by calling `qs.parse(received_data.toString());`. Hope this helps anyone who got stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone got the same problem: for me I couldn't solve it directly so I was forced to use `query-string` in order to parse the data instead of `json.parse` it seems the data received emptiness was related to the failure of the JSON parser somehow. so I installed it with `npm install querystring` and used const `qs = require('querystring');` in order to invoque the parser by calling `qs.parse(received_data.toString());`.

Hope this helps anyone who got stuck in the same situation.